# How to trigger css3 rotate effect by clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs. One is applied the rotate effect and another would trigger by clicking.

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $("#d1").addClass(".spinEffect");
  });
});
```

```css
#d1,
#d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

#d2 {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}

.spinEffect {
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s 1 linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
</div>
<div id="d2">
</div>
<a href=#>click me</a>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yNT3L/) is the demo page. I know the problem should be in js, could someone tell me how to modify it?

It's working when I remove the `.`

But when I click the link, it only work once. How can I fix that?

Comment: I edited my answer for your second question

Comment: You should also include the other vendor prefixes, as well as the spec version of the CSS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error near your `addClass`, you should put `$("#d1").addClass("spinEffect");` and not ".spinEffect", the `.` is useless there ;)

For your second question, just add `infinite` in your css

```
.spinEffect{
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want the box to turn once every time you click on the button you can achieve it with the following method

```
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    var $d1 = $("#d1"); //little optimization because we will use it more than once
    $d1.removeClass("spinEffect");
    setTimeout(function(){$d1.addClass("spinEffect")},0);
  });
});
```

You may ask why the `setTimeout`, it's because otherwise, the class is re-added to quickly for the CSS to trigger the effect ;)

Comment: but i only want the div to spin one time by each click

Answer (score 2):

all you have do is just remove the '.' from class name in js

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#d1").addClass("spinEffect");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this entirely in CSS and eschew the javascript completely (assuming the target browsers support the `:target` pseudo-class)

`:target` selects whichever element has the ID specified by the hash portion of the url, for example: `http://localhost/#d1` would be the URL after clicking the link in this answer.

**Note** I realized that this means the animation would only happen once.  So if this was for a situation where the link could be clicked multiple times, definitely go with the JS solution (though I think you'll have to remove the class and add it again to re-trigger the animation)

HTML:

```
<div id="d1">

</div>

<div id="d2">

</div>

<a href="#d1">click me</a>
```

CSS:

```
#d1, #d2{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }

    #d2{
        background-color: green;
        -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
    }

    /* or #d1:target */
    :target{
        -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s 1 linear;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}   
    }
```