# How can i spin an image -360 degrees and +360 degrees using the -webkit and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I found an example  of an infinite spinning div - [How to trigger css3 rotate effect by clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234557/how-to-trigger-css3-rotate-effect-by-clicking#new-answer) and here it is on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yNT3L/ here is the code used on jsFiddle -

//css

```
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

#d2{
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}

.spinEffect{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s 1 linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
```

//jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#d1").addClass(".spinEffect");
    });
});
```

it seems to be targeting the spin element of the -webkit and im just wondering how can i set the value of the spin element to 360 degrees and another div to -360 degrees?

Comment: It should be $("#d1").addClass("spinEffect"); instead of $("#d1").addClass(".spinEffect");

Comment: apologies! the bit of css i missed at the top is #d1, #d2{

Comment: btw, with webkit you are targeting only specific browser, use "animation" as in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp for support to wider browser.

Comment: Easy mistake, I spotted that and forgot to change it here, thank you though ! , just figuring out how to make both divs spin in opposite directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spin` is a custom name for the keyframes specification, it's not built into webkit. All you need to do is create a new keyframes item with a different name, and refer to that.

```
#d3{
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-animation: spinreverse 10s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinreverse {
    0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}   
}
```

I updated your jsfiddle as http://jsfiddle.net/yNT3L/157/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery for that. Also spin is not a built in function or method of webkit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/yNT3L/156/

CSS:

```
#d1 {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-animation: antispin 10s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes antispin {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
}
```

You can study more about animation here :http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/.